# Storing and retrieving files from a file storage in a web application

Tags: file, google-cloud-storage, storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a web application where the users would like to upload files to a file storage from within the same web application. I mean, the users should not navigate away and go to an external site just to upload files. They should be able to upload files from right from their own website to some file storage.

And once the file is uploaded, the user would like to come back a few days later to view the files they uploaded before. Perhaps the file storage could store the file together with the user's ID as reference so when they log back in their website, they could view what files were previously uploaded to the file storage.

What is the best file storage (either paid or free) you recommend that I can use and integrate into my website?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Google Cloud Storage with [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample) or [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage). Both will let you upload file through your App Engine app. As for the user ID and reference part, you can simply code it in: You can store the file ownership reference somewhere like in [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview), so you can authenticate your customers before letting them retrieve their storage files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using a web application such as asp.net. And want to upload a file using a 'browse button' from within the web application. Could you show me a working example?
Looks like the 'App Engine Flexible' using Python, could i use one for my node.js project?

Comment: would you have a sample code that could show me how to upload and view files in \Google storage from a .Net web app?

Comment: Yes there are multiple language options (you can see it in the tabs. I am not sure why using a "browse button" is different. Simply use the library and API provided and code JS frontend that accepts a file with a "browse button" and then send it to your application to process. We don't have a specific sample code for that specific need but the over API can be adapt to be used with any UI / frontend implementation you choose to code.